# removing section & product from urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Our site system produces urls like this

section.php/4/1/offers-events

product/12/surprise-deal

Right now we use this to take out the .php

```
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?).php/(.*?)$ $1.php?$2 [NC]
```

Would really like to be able to take out 'section' and 'product' from the url or be able to change those names to something more seo beneficial for the site.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: If you remove "section" and "product", how does your server know if a request is for the section.php or the product?

Comment: it would be better to renamed 'section' restaurant with url rewrite if possible